# Error in e.Item.FindControl("ID").ClientID as HtmlSelect

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing

I am having this error, don't know what seems to be the error.

> "Cannot convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' via a reference conversion,
>   boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null
>   type conversion"

The code that causes the error above is as follows:

```
protected void RptFaqsAnswer_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    (e.Item.FindControl("myselect").ClientID as HtmlSelect).Items[0].Attributes.Add("display", "none");
    ...
}
```

In .aspx page I have this select tag as a child of a "repeater."

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFaqsAnswer" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptFaqsAnswer_ItemDataBound">
    <select runat="server" id="myselect">
        <option value="c1">Choice 1</option>
        ...
    </select>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What seems to be the reason of this error.

Thanks

Rj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
e.Item.FindControl("myselect") as HtmlSelect
```

instead of

```
e.Item.FindControl("myselect").ClientID as HtmlSelect
```

It was the `ClientID` you were trying to convert which is why you were getting the error

Comment: I tried your code and it works.  But somehow the option that I want to hide is still showing in IE, even though its property was set to style="display: none;"  what seems to be the error on this?

Comment: with what you did I think it looks like this `<tag display="none" />` when it should be `<tag style="display:none" />`

Comment: try `tag.Style.Add("display","none")` or `tag.Attributes.Add("CssClass","hidden")`

Comment: there's no attribute as "tag" next to item[].  how should i implement it? thanks

Comment: in your case, `tag` should be replaced with `items[0]` I think. i.e. `items[0].Style.Add("display","none")`